# Unable to send contact form using Ajax with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 forms in my page, one is for contact page and the another one is for registration purposes.

I am using —almost— exactly the same thing for both forms.
All I am changing are the fields that I need to send.

I created I JSBin in case you want to take a look at the contact form which is working properly: https://jsbin.com/fetexumune/1/edit?html,js

Now, here I have the code for the register form which is not working:

HTML:

```
<form id="register-submit" method="post" action="register.php" class="register-form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name *" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name *" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email *" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" name="cemail" id="cemail" placeholder="Confirm Email *" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password *" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password *" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country *" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone # *" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <select class="selectpicker " required="required" id="area" name="area" placeholder="Select Field *">
                <option value="">Select Your Field *</option>
                <option value="IT / Software">IT / Software</option>
                <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
                <option value="Politics">Politics</option>
                <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
                <option value="Music">Music</option>
                <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="details" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Send any other detail (optional)"></textarea>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h4>Credit Card Information:</h4>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="nameoncard" id="nameoncard" placeholder="Name on Card *"  required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="ccnumber" id="ccnumber" placeholder="Card Number *" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="expiry-month">Expiration Date *</label>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <select name="expiry-month" id="expiry-month" required="required">
                            <option value="01">Jan (01)</option>
                            <option value="02">Feb (02)</option>
                            <option value="03">Mar (03)</option>
                            <option value="04">Apr (04)</option>
                            <option value="05">May (05)</option>
                            <option value="06">June (06)</option>
                            <option value="07">July (07)</option>
                            <option value="08">Aug (08)</option>
                            <option value="09">Sep (09)</option>
                            <option value="10">Oct (10)</option>
                            <option value="11">Nov (11)</option>
                            <option value="12">Dec (12)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select name="expiry-year" id="expiry-year" required="required">
                            <option value="17">2017</option>
                            <option value="18">2018</option>
                            <option value="19">2019</option>
                            <option value="20">2020</option>
                            <option value="21">2021</option>
                            <option value="22">2022</option>
                            <option value="23">2023</option>
                            <option value="24">2024</option>
                            <option value="25">2025</option>
                            <option value="26">2026</option>
                            <option value="27">2027</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input type="number" name="ccv" id="ccv" placeholder="Card CVV: Security Code *" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="register">
        <hr>
        <h4>Choose The Proper Services:</h4>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" value="All Services"> All Services
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Content Strategy" name="services" id="a1"> Content Strategy
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="ppc" name="services" id="a2"> Social Media Marketing
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="social" name="services" id="a3"> Search Engine Optimization

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="ads" name="services" id="a4"> Advanced Web Analytics
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="e-marketing" name="services" id="a5"> Email Marketing
            </label>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>

    <div>
        <section id="pricelist">
            <div>
                <div class="row pricelist-title">
                    <div class=" text-center">
                        <h2 class="title">Web Ads Promo Plan Options</h2>
                        <p class="sub-title">We provide the best packages for all your needs.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <ul class="price">
                                <li class="header">START UP</li>
                                <li class="grey"><label for="plan1">Choose <input type="checkbox" value="plan1" id="plan1" name="plan"></label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="table-columns">
                            <ul class="price">
                                <li class="header bg-gold">SME</li>
                                <li class="grey"><label for="plan2">Choose <input type="checkbox" value="plan2" id="plan2" name="plan"></label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="table-columns">
                            <ul class="price">
                                <li class="header bg-black">ENTERPRISE</li>
                                <li class="grey"><label for="plan3">Choose <input type="checkbox" value="plan3" id="plan3" name="plan"></label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="table-columns">
                            <ul class="price">
                                <li class="header bg-green">All Ads Package</li>
                                <li class="grey"><label for="plan4">Choose <input type="checkbox" value="plan4" id="plan4" name="plan"></label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" required="required">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'status'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Thank you! One of our agents will contact you soon.'
    );

    $debug_log = "./debugginglog.txt";
    $currContent = file_get_contents($debug_log);
    file_put_contents($debug_log, "Trying to send email ... \n");

    $subject = 'Registration Form';
    $firstName = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['firstName']));
    $lastName = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['lastName']));
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $confirmEmail = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['confirmEmail']));
    $password = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['password']));
    $confirmPass = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['confirmPass']));
    $country = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['country']));
    $number = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['number']));
    $area = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['area']));
    $details = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['details']));
    $nameoncard = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['nameoncard']));
    $ccnumber = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['ccnumber']));
    $expirymonth = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['expirymonth']));
    $expiryyear = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['expiryyear']));
    $ccv = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['ccv']));
    $services = @trim(stripslashes(implode(', ', $_POST['services'])));
    $plan = @trim(stripslashes(implode(', ', $_POST['plan'])));

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'name@mail.domain'; //replace with your email

    $body =
        'Name: ' . $firstName . "\n\n" .
        'Last Name: ' . $lastName . "\n\n" .
        'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" .
        'Confirm Email: ' . $confirmEmail . "\n\n" .
        'Password: ' . $password . "\n\n" .
        'Confirm Pass: ' . $confirmPass . "\n\n" .
        'Country: ' . $country . "\n\n" .
        'Number: ' . $number . "\n\n" .
        'Field: ' . $area . "\n\n" .
        'Details: ' . $details . "\n\n" .
        'Name on card: ' . $nameoncard . "\n\n" .
        'Card number: ' . $ccnumber . "\n\n" .
        'Expiration Date: ' . $expirymonth . "/" . $expiryyear . "\n\n" .
        'Security code: ' . $ccv . "\n\n" .
        'Services: ' . $services . "\n\n" .
        'Plan: ' . $plan . "\n\n";

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    $currContent = file_get_contents($debug_log);
    file_put_contents($debug_log, "Response ..." . $success . "\n");

    echo json_encode($status);

die;
?>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('#register-submit').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var firstName = $('#fname').val();
        var lastName = $('#lName').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var confirmEmail = $('#cemail').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var confirmPass = $('#cpassword').val();
        var country = $('#country').val();
        var number = $('#phone').val();
        var area = $('#area').val();
        var details = $('#details').val();
        var nameoncard = $('#nameoncard').val();
        var ccnumber = $('#ccnumber').val();
        var expirymonth = $('#expiry-month').val();
        var expiryyear = $('#expiry-year').val();
        var ccv = $('#ccv').val();
        var services = [];
        $('[name="services"]:checked').each(function (i, e) {
            services.push(e.value);
        });
        var plan = [];
        $('[name="plan"]:checked').each(function (i, e) {
            plan.push(e.value);
        });

        var data =  {
            'firstName': firstName,
            'lastName': lastName,
            'email': email,
            'confirmEmail': confirmEmail,
            'password': password,
            'confirmPass': confirmPass,
            'country': country,
            'number': number,
            'area': area,
            'details': details,
            'nameoncard': nameoncard,
            'ccnumber': ccnumber,
            'expirymonth': expirymonth,
            'expiryyear': expiryyear,
            'ccv': ccv,
            'services': services,
            'plan': plan,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (message) {
                var response = message;
                console.log('response top:', response);
                if (response.status === 'success') {
                    $('.register-form')[0].reset();
                    console.log('response:', response);
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('response:', textStatus);
                console.log('XMLHttpRequest:', XMLHttpRequest);
                console.log('errorThrown:', errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

The weirdest thing for me is the fact that the contact form is working properly and the register form doesn't.

In the `success` part of the ajax call, I have a `console.log('response:', response);` which is printing this in the console:

> response: {status: "success", message: "Thank you! One of our agents will contact you soon."}

It means it is giving me a response message coming from the success section when `response.status === 'success'`.

So, what am I doing wrong?

***EDIT***

I know one is working and the other doesn't, is because I am testing with my personal email account.
So I am receiving the emails of the contact form, but I am not getting anything from the register form.

Comment: response.status === 'success'. is response.status == 'success' (JUST 2 = to equal a string)

Comment: how do you know it is not working? are you receiving an email or is it based on the debug_log?

Comment: *The weirdest thing for me is the fact that the contact form is working properly and the register form doesn't.* how you know one is working and other is not?

Comment: @joshuamiller I am not getting the email in my inbox.

Comment: @B.Desai because I am sending the emails to my inbox.

Comment: How do you know the form isnt working? Maybe its receiving the data fine, just the email part is not working properly. Test each part separately and check. Also check your spam folder

Comment: Hey @B.Desai this is not a duplicate since I am able to do it with one form and not with the other. Which I means I am doing the proper process but there is something weird happening with the register form. Remove that, otherwise my question will be closed or something like that.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer here we can see only **one `mail` function**. So how could you say you are getting mail of `contact form` but not of `register form`

Comment: @B.Desai sorry but I didn't get what you said.

Comment: @B.Desai I placed an URL to the other function: https://jsbin.com/fetexumune/1/edit?html,js at the beginning of the question. Which is separately from the register function.

Comment: Try to place static content in `body` then execute your code. If you receive mail then debug your body content may be issue is there

Answer (score 0):

Add to $.ajax param `dataType: 'json'` and to get data from form you can use `$('#register-submit').serializeArray();`